# Ubuntu 19.10 can't able to access the internet in the VMware Workstation

Tags: networking, virtualization, 19.10, vmware, vmware-workstation

I had installed Ubuntu 19.10 a couple of months ago in my VMware. Everything was working fine. But today I noticed that Ubuntu can't able to access the internet.

There is no issue with my internet. The network is working fine on my host machine. I have a couple of other virtual machines. The Internet is working fine there also. It's not working only in Ubuntu even though it shows the network is connected.

[image]

I use `NAT` as my Network Connection settings.

[image]

I rebooted the virtual machine, changed the network connection `NAT` to `Bridged` but nothing worked

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is commonly related to time synchonisation. run

```
date -u
```

in both your host and your guest and compare the results. If the date and time in the guest is significantly different, you can run the command

```
hwclock --set --date="2020-05-11 12:37:25"  --utc
```

but being careful to change my date and time above to the one given by your host system.

Comment: Thank You, Sir. It worked!.